# CanCanCan. How to show only items that belong to that current logged in admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I went through the Rails tutorial and Cancancan, ActiveAdmin documentation already.  Now I stuck when trying to make the authorization that allow an admin_user that currently logged in only can see the notifications that belongs to that admin_user.
Here is my code:

```
def initialize(admin_user)
    can :read, AdminUser, id: admin_user.id
    can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: "Dashboard", namespace_name: "admin"
    can :read, Notification, id: notification.admin_user_id
end
```

I tried to play around with notification.admin_user_id part but I always get the error

```
undefined local variable or method 'notification'
```

Comment: [Have you checked the docs?](https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html#using-the-cancan-adapter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what's `Notification` but if let's say `Notification` `belongs_to :admin` and thus have `admin_id` column, I believe you should write it like that

`can :read, Notification, admin_id: admin_user.id`

In other words you shouldn't set up the ability on those notifications which have particular `id`. You should do that on the notifications that have particular `admin_id` or `admin_user_id` or `user_id` or whatever key that points to `admin_user` that the notification belongs to. This way you say actually "let admin_user be able to read the notifications which belong to him"